# start time value is not correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In actual code below in view section I am getting FormattedStartTime value at least 4 hours more than what it should be. Like if actual value is 2 p.m. then it is showing 18:00 instead of 15:00. How can I fix this issue?

```
Model:

public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

public string FormattedStartTime => StartDate?.ToString("HH:mm");

public bool HideTimestamp { get; set; }

       View:

        if (!Model.HideTimestamp)
                    {
                      <span>@Model.FormattedStartDate @Model.FormattedStartTime</span>
                }
```

Comment: This has to be a time-zone issue.

Comment: how to fix this time zone issue? can I subtract hours somehow, somewhere?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=public+string+FormattedStartTime+%3D%3E+StartDate%3F.ToString(%22HH%3Amm%22)%3B&oq=public+string+FormattedStartTime+%3D%3E+StartDate%3F.ToString(%22HH%3Amm%22)%3B&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23++offset+datetime+timezone+

Comment: Use a breakpoint and see if the time on the server is the same as what is printed on the page. It should be, so the issue is probably when you send it from the client to the server initially.

Comment: You haven't showed us where the value originates from.  Nothing in what you posted here will change the value in the way you describe.  Please go up the stack to show us how you get the start time.

Comment: Time coming in FormattedStartTime is the UTC time. I need to convert this time in string value which is UTC time into my local time zone time which is Eastern time zone. How can I do that??

Comment: Value originated from the field. So if select 2 p.m. in the field then it should display 14:00 in the razor view. It is displaying 18:00 as it is changing that into UTC time. So we need to convert it back from the UTC time to 2p.m. on front end or view.  Formatted StartDate is defined in Model.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it right with the proper culture. Your server or application is set be on a different time zone .

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
string FormattedDate = myDate.ToString("HH:mm", ci);
```

You should validate your variable as well as it could be null.

Comment: it does not work as start time value is the same and does not change.

Comment: Culture does not affect time zone. They are orthogonal

Comment: Time coming in FormattedStartTime is the UTC time. I need to convert this time in string value which is UTC time into my local time zone time which is Eastern time zone. How can I do that??

Comment: After debug value is StartDate = 4/13/2017 7:00:00 PM and FormattedStartTime = 19:00

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with timezone offsets affecting what was being displayed. We weren't using Razor to print the time as HTML, but pass it through JSON in an Angular app. However, if you're posting a time to the server with AJAX, you'll encounter the same issue. (If you were to send JSON back to the client, the time offset would be doubled.)

Assuming you're using Newtonsoft (if you're not, you should) for your JSON serialization, you can just add the following to wherever you set up your stack (Global.asax, OWIN, etc):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                   .Formatters
                   .JsonFormatter
                   .SerializerSettings
                   .Converters
                   .Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
                   {
                       DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal
                   });
```

What that `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` will do is change the serializer so that it converts any dates that are sent to/from your models back to UTC time before setting the properties. This will eliminate the timezone offsets that can occur when an action happens outside the timezone the server is set to.

Comment: All code I see is default  so donno what to change or add anything to that default code. Somehow that default code is not showing proper value from the back end.